# Load bootloader on ESP32

Tags: esp8266, esp32, ttl, bootloader, c++

I'm trying to load the bootloader to my esp32 or that's what I think I need, because when I connect it with USB to TTL, and I connect TX with RX, Rx with TX and GND with GND and I reset the micro by console I see the following data (115200 baud )
[image]

And so I have connected the device

[image]

But when I want to load a program in c++ it never connects, no matter how much I press the boot button.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Rx line is working on the ESP 32 side by probing it with the logic analyzer or oscilloscope. Check and see if you need any hard work control lines to get into boot mode or just RX.

Comment: If the Rx and Tx are well connected, I measure them with the oscilloscope at the input of the pin and I have a square signal

Answer (score 0):

ESP32 has a built in bootloader, and what you see on the screen is the bootloader loading an application (apparently for BLE).  What you presumably are trying to do is load other software onto the board.  For this, you want the bootloader to be in download mode.

Go back to your terminal screen and this time, hold the boot button while you press the reset button.  You will see something like this:

[image]

This is what your c++ loader is looking for.  You may be able to make this work if you go back to that, and while it says "Connecting....", hold *boot* and press *reset*.

Most ESP32 tools and accessories are set up to do this automatically for you. In particular, that c++ loader will be trying to operate the buttons via the connection to the board.  It's hard to tell from your picture what is doing what, but I see an unused wire which suggests you don't have everything hooked up.  What you have is the simplest serial connection, and that may be good enough for now, being able to start the boot loader manually.

Comment: Hello friends!
If I press that I get this: ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46

rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x1b (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:6932
load:0x40078000,len:13712
load:0x40080400,len:4260
entry 0x400806e4